# Add missing values to a list in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, list, xamarin.forms

I have a custom object list which has month and another int value. I am getting this list from the database. So data coming from a web service as JSON. Sometimes month is not consecutive. Sometimes some month get missing. For example if this is month 7,

then months in list may contains something like this.
{1,2,3,6,7}

so I want to add the missing months which are 4,5 ---- 
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

other value should be 0 (NEW_REC_COUNT)

My Object class

```
public class NewData
{
    public int MONTH { get; set; }
    public int NEW_REC_COUNT { get; set; }
}
```

Sample Json

```
[
    {
        "MONTH": 1,
        "NEW_REC_COUNT": 19
    },
    {
        "MONTH": 2,
        "NEW_REC_COUNT": 5
    },
    {
        "MONTH": 3,
        "NEW_REC_COUNT": 2
    },
    {
        "MONTH": 6,
        "NEW_REC_COUNT": 9
    },
    {
        "MONTH": 7,
        "NEW_REC_COUNT": 3
    }
]
```

Comment: Where/how are you creating this list? Without context, the best we can tell you to do is just use `List.Add()` *somehow*.

Comment: I am getting values from the web service. I have updated the answer. My bad, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a lot of data, you can try a smiple *loop* and `Insert` omitted items into the list:

```
List<NewData> list = ...

// If list is not guarantee to be sorted
list.Sort((a, b) => a.MONTH.CompareTo(b.MONTH));

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; ++i) {
  NewData current = list[i];
  NewData next = list[i + 1];     

  // Do we have a hole at position i + 1? 
  if (current.MONTH + 1 < next.MONTH) {
    list.Insert(i + 1, new NewData() {
      MONTH = current.MONTH + 1,  // Omitted month
      NEW_REC_COUNT = 0,          // Default value
    });
  }
}
```

**Edit:** If we want months from `1` up and including the current month (`DateTime.Today.Month`), we can use *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  List<NewData> list = ...

  // Let's generalize a bit if you want, say Q3 period
  int fromMonth = 1;
  int upToMonth = DateTime.Today.Month; // or 7 for testing

  list = Enumerable
    .Range(fromMonth, upToMonth - fromMonth + 1)
    .Select(month =>
          list.FirstOrDefault(item => item.MONTH == month)
       ?? new NewData() { MONTH = month,       // Omitted month 
                          NEW_REC_COUNT = 0 }) // Default value
    .ToList();
```

If you want to modify *existing* `list`:

```
  list.AddRange(Enumerable
    .Range(fromMonth, upToMonth - fromMonth + 1)
    .Where(month => !list.Any(item => item.MONTH == month))
    .Select(month => new NewData() { 
       MONTH = month, 
       NEW_REC_COUNT = 0 })
    .ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. This code working well but little thing, what if we missing the month 1? Lets say that the List is starting with month 2, How should i add month 1?

Comment: My current code *doesn't add* month `1`, it only *fills the holes*. Shall we add month(s) after the last one? E.g. `{2, 3, 4} -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`? If we shall, what should be the end month?

Comment: Ok we can add. End month is always should be current month. But current month also may be not in the list. that could happen also. Eg: current month is 7, but list only may contains { 3, 4, 5, 6}..... so we need to add 1,2,7.

Comment: @D.madushanka: I see; in this case we can check all the monthes in the desired range and create omitted items if necessary. I've edited the answer

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, I guess your last update is similar to my answer, is it?

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar: The differencies between answers: 1. I don't use `Except` which removes all duplicates and which wants that both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` *be implemented* (current `NewData` class *doesn't do it*). 2. I use `fromMonth..upToMonth` range (not `1.. Max(MONTH)`). 3. I do the task in one query thanks to `??` operator. However, the approach is similar: when we have to work with given range, `Enumerable.Range(...)` is very convenient

Answer (score 2):

You can try below approach,

1. Select all months (int value) from list using `Select`

   ```
     var months = NewDataList.Select(x => x.MONTH); // This will give you all integers i.e MONTHs.
   ```
2. Find `Max()` from months and create Range from `1... maxMonths`

   ```
   var maxMonths = months.Max();
   var oneTomaxMonths = Enumerable.Range(1,maxMonths).ToList();
   ```

Now you have 2 lists i.e. `months` and `oneToMaxMonths`, use Except to get missing Months from list of New Data

```
var results = oneTomaxMonths.Except(months);
```

Foreach result create new instance with `NEW_REC_COUNT = 0`

POC : [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xUuBjI)

Comment: @D.madushanka did you get chance to look into my answer

Comment: That's correct, but I'd rather put it as one single query; +1

Comment: ;) thanks @DmitryBychenko, your +1 means a lot to me